# FFmpeg: unspecified pixel format when opening video with custom context

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am trying to decode a video with a custom context. The purpose is that I want to decode the video directly from memory. In the following code, I am reading from file in the `read` function passed to `avio_alloc_context` - but this is just for testing purposes.

I think I've read any post there is on Stackoverflow or on any other website related to this topic. At least I definitely tried my best to do so. While there is much in common, the details differ: people set different flags, some say `av_probe_input_format` is required, some say it isn't, etc. And for some reason nothing works for me.

My problem is that the pixel format is unspecified (see output below), which is why I run into problems later when calling `sws_getContext`. I checked `pFormatContext->streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec->pix_fmt`, and it is -1.

Please note my comments `// things I tried` and `// seems not to help` in the code. I think, the answer might be hidden somehwere there. I tried many combinations of hints that I've read so far, but I am missing a detail I guess.

The problem is not the video file, because when I go the standard way and just call `avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, pFilePath, NULL, NULL)` without a custom context, everything runs fine.

The code compiles and runs as is.

```
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *f;

static int read(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size) {
    if (feof(f)) return -1;
    return fread(buf, 1, buf_size, f);
}

int openVideo(const char *pFilePath) {
    const int bufferSize = 32768;
    int ret;

    av_register_all();

    f = fopen(pFilePath, "rb");
    uint8_t *pBuffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(bufferSize + AVPROBE_PADDING_SIZE);
    AVIOContext *pAVIOContext = avio_alloc_context(pBuffer, bufferSize, 0, NULL,
                      &read, NULL, NULL);

    if (!f || !pBuffer || !pAVIOContext) {
        printf("error: open / alloc failed\n");
        // cleanup...
        return 1;
    }

    AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    pFormatContext->pb = pAVIOContext;

    const int readBytes = read(NULL, pBuffer, bufferSize);

    printf("readBytes = %i\n", readBytes);

    if (readBytes <= 0) {
        printf("error: read failed\n");
        // cleanup...
        return 2;
    }

    if (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
        printf("error: fseek failed\n");
        // cleanup...
        return 3;
    }

    // required for av_probe_input_format
    memset(pBuffer + readBytes, 0, AVPROBE_PADDING_SIZE);

    AVProbeData probeData;
    probeData.buf = pBuffer;
    probeData.buf_size = readBytes;
    probeData.filename = "";
    probeData.mime_type = NULL;

    pFormatContext->iformat = av_probe_input_format(&probeData, 1);

    // things I tried:
    //pFormatContext->flags = AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO;
    //pFormatContext->iformat->flags |= AVFMT_NOFILE;
    //pFormatContext->iformat->read_header = NULL;

    // seems not to help (therefore commented out here):
    AVDictionary *pDictionary = NULL;
    //av_dict_set(&pDictionary, "analyzeduration", "8000000", 0);
    //av_dict_set(&pDictionary, "probesize", "8000000", 0);

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, "", NULL, &pDictionary)) < 0) {
        char buffer[4096];
        av_strerror(ret, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("error: avformat_open_input failed: %s\n", buffer);
        // cleanup...
        return 4;
    }

    printf("retrieving stream information...\n");

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatContext, NULL)) < 0) {
        char buffer[4096];
        av_strerror(ret, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("error: avformat_find_stream_info failed: %s\n", buffer);
        // cleanup...
        return 5;
    }

    printf("nb_streams = %i\n", pFormatContext->nb_streams);

    // further code...

    // cleanup...
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    openVideo("video.mp4");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I get:
readBytes = 32768
retrieving stream information...
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xdf8d20] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xdf8d20] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 640x360, 351 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
nb_streams = 2

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to WLGfx, here is the solution: The only thing that was missing was the seek function. Apparently, implementing it is mandatory for decoding. It is important to return the new offset - and not 0 in case of success (some solutions found in the web just return the return value of fseek, and that is wrong). Here is the minimal solution that made it work:

```
static int64_t seek(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence) {
    if (whence == SEEK_SET && fseek(f, offset, SEEK_SET) == 0) {
        return offset;
    }
    // handling AVSEEK_SIZE doesn't seem mandatory
    return -1;
}
```

Of course, the call to `avio_alloc_context` needs to be adapted accordingly:

```
AVIOContext *pAVIOContext = avio_alloc_context(pBuffer, bufferSize, 0, NULL,
                      &read, NULL, &seek);
```

Comment: Did try you increase `analyzeduration` and `probesize` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. See below my comment "seems not to help" in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as yours is a file based stream then it is seekable so you can provide the AVIO seek when creating the AVIOContext:

```
avioContext = avio_alloc_context((uint8_t *)avio_buffer, AVIO_QUEUE_SIZE * PKT_SIZE7,
    0,
    this, // *** This is your data pointer to a class or other data passed to the callbacks
    avio_ReadFunc,
    NULL,
    avio_SeekFunc);
```

Handle the seeking with this callback: (You can cast `ptr` to your class or other data structure)

```
int64_t FFIOBufferManager::avio_SeekFunc(void *ptr, int64_t pos64, int whence) {
    // SEEK_SET(0), SEEK_CUR(1), SEEK_END(2), AVSEEK_SIZE
    // ptr is cast to your data or class

    switch (whence) {
    case 0 : // SEEK_SET
    ... etc
    case (AVSEEK_SIZE) : // get size
        return -1; // if you're unable to get the size
        break;
    }

    // set new position in the file

    return (int64_t)new_pos; // new position
}
```

You can also define the codec and the probesize when attaching the AVIOContext to the AVFormatContext. This allows ffmpeg to seek in the stream to better determine the format.

```
context->pb = ffio->avioContext;
context->flags = AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO;
context->iformat = av_find_input_format("mpegts"); // not necessary
context->probesize = 1200000;
```

So far I haven't had the need for `av_probe_input_format`, but then again my streams are mpegts.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Added a comment to the avio_alloc_context function to mention how the `ptr` is used in the callbacks.

Comment: You saved my day! Adding the seek function made it work - I didn't need the rest. In my case, I do need the probe, otherwise it crashes, plus I don't know the file format, so can't hardcode it. Will add the solution at the end of my question. I am curious from where you know what seek needs to handle/return. I couldn't find any useful information in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.2/avio_8h.html#a853f5149136a27ffba3207d8520172a5) regarding this. I had tried with seek, but didn't know I have to return the new offset, so I just returned 0 in case of success, therefore it failed.

Comment: The documentation for any ffmpeg stuff is pretty sparse. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/489450/Creating-Custom-FFmpeg-IO-Context is where I originally started with the AVIOContext. I also found one or two other resources but with minimal explanation. Mine was trial and error until it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Although the seek was the right answer in your situation, the fact is in my case it's not possible because I have to stream the data and in that situation a seek is just not possible.

**So I had to look into: why is a seek required?**

From what the ffmpeg docs say, they will cache some data so that way they can seek back if required by the current encoder/decoder. But that buffer is relatively small (you probably don't want to cache 100's of Mb of data).

The fact is that MP4 saves some metadata at the end of the file (once it's known). When reading that format, the decoder wants to seek to a position really very far in the file (near the end) and read what is called the `moov` atom. Without that info, the system doesn't want to decompress your data.

What I had to do to fix this issue is move that `moov` atom with the following command:

```sh
ffmpeg -i far.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -movflags +faststart close.mp4
```

*`faststart`* means you do not have to stream the entire file to start playing (decoding) the file.